# WP Mail isn't sending user account messages, does send from plugins

Tags: email, user-registration, wp-mail

I'm running WP 4.6.1 and can't seem to send out any user account related emails. Specifically, notify user their account is created (the option is checked when creating accounts in the admin) and password reset emails don't send. No errors, just nothing shows in the receiver email account or spam. Email addresses are verified spelled correctly.

Interestingly, Gravity Forms and WooCommerce emails seem to be sent through fine (marked as spam, but at least they go through). The email notifying the administrator a new account has been created also does arrive.

I'm not using any SMTP or other email plugins at the moment, just WordPresses default mailer. The domain name is not on any blacklists, according to mxtoolbox.com.

Is there a hook or option I've overlooked that disables these emails? Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, hooks have nothing to do here, all the emails you mentioned (WordPress Gravity Forms and WooCommerce) use the same function `wp_mail`.

I strongly believe this is blocked outside of WordPress, and I suggest you use a SMTP server with a real email address, you can use [Postman SMTP Mailer/Email Log](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postman-smtp/) which will also help troubleshot emails related problems.

Comment: Ended up doing this; installed Postman and tied it to a SendGrid account. Thanks for the feedback! Just irritating email is so unreliable from web servers.